# Profunctor but with three contravariant parameters

Tags: haskell, category-theory, profunctor

I've got a type `T` with the following function defined on it:

```
tMap :: (a' -> a) -> (b' -> b) -> (c' -> c) -> (d -> d') -> T a b c d -> T a' b' c' d'
tMap = ...
```

Basically `T` is a profunctor but with three contravariant parameters instead of the usual one.

I thought what might be nice is if I could make my type just an ordinary profunctor. Which would save me having to write up special syntax for my type, and I could reuse any existing machinery in the profunctor library. So my first try was this:

```
data U abc d where
  U :: T a b c d -> U (a, b, c) d

instance Profunctor U where
  dimap f g (U x) = U (tMap ... x)
```

But this just doesn't work for a number of different reasons, one of which is that I can't see a way to exact `a' -> a` out of `(a', b', c') -> (a, b, c)`, and also that you could pass `Int -> (Int, Int, Int)`, and then you're stuck as there's no `U Int blah` constructor.

I suspect what I'm trying to do is impossible, but I thought I'd ask incase I was missing some transformation that reasonably makes my type a profunctor, aside from something like just ignoring the first two contravariant arguments by doing something like:

```
instance Profunctor (T a b) ...
```

Comment: A simpler question that boils down to the same would be about a contravariant functor with two arguments.

Comment: An even simpler question would be about a bifunctor. 
Anyway, there isn't that much machinery for profunctors. What you might want to do is to define three `Profunctor` instances for your `T`, one for each pair (a, d), (b, d), and (c, d).

Comment: Your majigger may be a profunctor, but it's not a `Profunctor`. Just like `Functor` restricts itself to Hask endofunctors, `Profunctor` restricts itself to profunctors with Hask as both input categories; but what you need is a product category for the contravariant bit, so you're hosed. Sorry.

Comment: @DanielWagner well, there are packages that actually support functors between different categories, such as [`data-category`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-category). The downside is of course that the common "**Hask** endofunctor" case isn't quite as simple anymore.